# IGBT(Insulated-gate bipolar transistor) Latch-up

Tags: fet, igbt

What will happen if the Parasitic transistor turn on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The device latches-up i a similar way to a thyristor or triac and cannot be turned off until the current is reduced by external means.

The IGBT is designed to minimize the possibility of latch-up occurring.

Please see [Insulated Gate Bipolar Transistor (IGBT) Basics](https://www.ixys.com/Documents/AppNotes/IXYS_IGBT_Basic_I.pdf)